# Flash plugin with rooted Android phones

Tags: android, flash

I have 2 Android phones that I use to test the app that I'm developing. One is rooted with CyanogenMod 7 and the other one is not rooted. Also both phones have Adobe Flash Player 11.1.111.6 installed.

After installing the APK to both phones, I tried the video playback. On the phone that was **NOT** rooted, it worked flawlessly. However on the rooted phone, I only got the audio to work with a blank video.

There was a "band-aid" fix that I found which tells me to remove all the permissions for the file

```
/data/data/PACKAGE_NAME/app_plugins/com.adobe.flashplayer/.macromedia/Flash_Player/config.data
```

According to the poster, this file restricts video playback of anything over 240p. Sorry but I don't have a link to that thread anymore.

After removing all permissions for that file, I ran the app again on the rooted phone and it worked like a charm.

What would be the best solution so that when I publish the app on the Android Market everyone who installs the app will not experience this problem on their phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a menu option, or prompt the user after trying several different non-exhaustive ways of determining if the device is rooted, or clearly document the problem so that your rooted users can apply the fix themselves, or clearly link to a separate app of yours that has no purpose but to apply this fix to rooted devices.  In the first two cases, when directed by the user, attempt to get root, make the change, and then remember that you made the change.

The value of a prompt and of memory is that e.g. Superuser won't alarm the user when it requests the user's permission.

Comment: Thanks! Instead of creating a different app, I think I will put the fix within the app itself. I just need to know how to determine if the phone is rooted or not and how to apply the fix programmatically.

I'm not sure whether or not the reason behind this problem is because I messed up during the rooting process. This might still work with other rooted phones.